# Add row in spreadsheet (List-based feed) but it not works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have used the bellow code to add row in spreadsheet (List-based feed) but it not works ...

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
GDataEntrySpreadsheetList *listEntry = [GDataEntrySpreadsheetList listEntry];
GDataSpreadsheetCustomElement *serialNo = [GDataSpreadsheetCustomElement elementWithName:@"SNo" stringValue:@"1"];
[array addObject:serialNo];
[listEntry setCustomElements:array];    
//then after finding the worksheet
GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet *service = [self spreadsheetService];
NSURL *feedURL = [addedWorkSheet listFeedURL];
[service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:listEntry 
         forFeedURL:feedURL 
             delegate:self 
                  didFinishSelector:@selector(addEntry:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
```

The above code gives error like:

error::-Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet.)" UserInfo=0x5fe2de0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=(We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet.), error=We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet.}

Please help me to solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This very misleading error can occur if the GDataEntrySpreadsheetList you're trying to insert contains no GDataSpreadsheetCustomElements that are relevant to the worksheet.

When creating a GDataSpreadsheetCustomElement, the string you use for "name" must match the value in the first row of the spreadsheet for the column you're interested in, EXCEPT that **it must be converted to all lower-case and have all spaces removed.**

Try replacing elementWithName:@"SNo" with elementWithName:@"sno"