# 2 legged oauth and spreadsheet updating

Tags: gdata, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I am using the google api to update some spreadsheets (using 2 legged oauth as explained [here](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/articles/2lo-in-tasks-for-admins.html), except that I check the Two legged access control box ).
Creating the spreadsheets work fine, creating new worksheets inside a spreadsheet also works fine. But I can not seem to interact with the data on the spreadsheet....

I get either:

using listFeed

We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet.

or

using CellFeed

com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran into both of these errors when learning the Google spreadsheets API. I wish Google did a better job documenting these.

My issue with the listFeed method was that I was using upper case letters and spaces in my GDataSpreadsheetCustomElement names. Google doesn't like this. Here is what I posted on a similar question: [Add row in spreadsheet (List-based feed) but it not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816634/add-row-in-spreadsheet-list-based-feed-but-it-not-works)

"This very misleading error can occur if the GDataEntrySpreadsheetList you're trying to insert contains no GDataSpreadsheetCustomElements that are relevant to the worksheet.

When creating a GDataSpreadsheetCustomElement, the string you use for "name" must match the value in the first row of the spreadsheet for the column you're interested in, EXCEPT that **it must be converted to all lower-case and have all spaces removed.**"

My issue with authentication using CellFeed was that I was using the wrong FeedURL. The feedURL you want when updating cells is [[worksheet cellsLink] URL]; where worksheet is the GDataEntryWorksheet object for the worksheet you're editing.